# How can i add google maps in django which takes a location from user and his desired location and then calculates the distance between the locations?

Tags: django, geodjango

I created a an app which adds map in page using 'https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/maps-django-web-applications-projects-mapbox.html' this refernce. Now i want to take userlocation and then user can enter his desired location and then calculates the distance between them.

Comment: The developer guide to Google Maps should help with this. Pass the origin and destination variables to their API and you'll get back a JSON response that includes the distance between those points. You can adjust the results based on different types of moving modes (driving, biking, walking, etc.).
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview

If you're looking for the shortest distance between two geocodes, a great circle calculation would likely address things without the need to ping an API. 
https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Using third party websites to get the api key will do the same thing as google maps api key does?